# Restart/Stop Nginx using my UserId without sudo permissions

Tags: nginx, service, sudo, restart, systemctl

I need to restart the nginx services installed via root using my user-id ie TAG1 without the help of sudo. Now we are using the below command to restart the Services

```
**COmmand : sudo /usr/bin/systemctl restart nginx**

So please provide us with some inputs how to restart nginx services using a newid without using SUDO permissions.
```

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:**
Using visudo, add the following to your sudoers file, replacing username with the proper username

```
USER        ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl restart nginx
```

This will allow the user to run "/usr/bin/systemctl restart nginx" with any or zero following attributes (ie. start|stop|restart).

References for more detail:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/692701/allowing-user-to-run-systemctl-systemd-services-without-password

https://serverfault.com/questions/69847/linux-how-to-give-a-user-permission-to-restart-apache

Comment: I Tried the above steps. Edited visudo sudoers file and added this line  tag1 ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl restart nginx at end of file. Saved that file. exit. Tried running /usr/bin/systemctl restart nginx using my user. Error : failed to restart nginx.service. intreactive Authentication is required

Comment: there's a "sudo" missing in front, so correct call would be: 'sudo /usr/bin/systemctl restart nginx'