# Facing Authentication error while restarting Nginx without Sudo

Tags: nginx, service, sudo, restart, application-restart

```
I have followed few blogs on implementing the restart service for nginx without sudo using my User ID. I completed all the steps as mentioned in blogs. But while am re-starting the Nginx Services without sudo am facing the below error.

**Command Used :** 
/usr/bin/systemctl restart nginx
**Log:**
Failed to restart nginx.service: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status nginx.service' for details.

**Reference:**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51019993/restart-stop-nginx-using-my-userid-without-sudo-permissions/51020325#51020325
https://askubuntu.com/questions/692701/allowing-user-to-run-systemctl-systemd-services-without-password
https://serverfault.com/questions/69847/linux-how-to-give-a-user-permission-to-restart-apache
```

Please help on resolving the error and restart nginx without sudo